# Почему Питон возвращает разный список

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Имеется такой кусок кода из программы - Список филиалов в виде списка словарей, и функция которая находит русское название для вывода его в шаблон. Периодически выводится значение на английском.
Пробовал return list(i.get('fil').values()) да он действительно список выводит по разному (не всегда). Почему так. Что это и как бороться с этим?. Python 3.5.3. На более позднем Питоне все нормально. Но обновить Питон пока боязно.

```
    list_fils = [{'fil': {'value': 'Москва', 'name': 'moscow'}},
       {'fil': {'value': 'Волгоград', 'name': 'volgograd'}},
       {'fil': {'value': 'Липецк', 'name': 'lipetsk'}},
       {'fil': {'value': 'Курск', 'name': 'kursk'}}]

    def name_fil_rus(name_fil):
        for i in list_fils:
            if name_fil in i.get('fil').values():
                return list(i.get('fil').values())[0]

    print(name_fil_rus('kursk'))
```

---

```
    Вывод когда return list(i.get('fil').values())
    python3.5 123.py
    ['kursk', 'Курск']
    python3.5 123.py
    ['kursk', 'Курск']
    python3.5 123.py
    ['Курск', 'kursk']
    python3.5 123.py
    ['kursk', 'Курск']
    python3.5 123.py
    ['Курск', 'kursk']
```

Comment: Потому что сохранение порядка записей в словаре не гарантировалось до версии Python 3.7 (насколько я помню). Как бороться - использовать [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: "Но обновить Питон пока боязно." - Python 3.5 фактически уже не поддерживается. Смело обновляйтесь до 3.8 - он стабильный, ничего не сломается.

Comment: Да это верно, будем обновляться.

Comment: И всё же лучше в данном случае сделать правильную структуру для поиска данных, а не полагаться на версию питона. )  Лучше, когда вы сами контролируете такие вещи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы в вашем случае просто сделал нормальные словари для перевода и брал значения уже оттуда, если поля словаря у вас жёстко заданы и заранее известно где что (если в `name` всегда английское название, а в `value` русское):

```py
list_fils = [{'fil': {'value': 'Москва', 'name': 'moscow'}},
   {'fil': {'value': 'Волгоград', 'name': 'volgograd'}},
   {'fil': {'value': 'Липецк', 'name': 'lipetsk'}},
   {'fil': {'value': 'Курск', 'name': 'kursk'}}]

eng_rus = {y['name']:y['value'] for x in list_fils for y in x.values()}
rus_eng = {y['value']:y['name'] for x in list_fils for y in x.values()}

print(eng_rus.get('kursk'))
```

Вывод:

```
Курск
```

В этом случае и перебора никакого не нужно, значение просто берётся из заранее подготовленного словаря.

В зависимости от задачи можно сделать и универсальный словарь для перевода в обе стороны, но не зная постановку задачи тут сложно сказать, что больше подойдёт.

Но в любом случае полагаться на порядок следования пар ключ-значение в словаре не стоит, хотя с какой-то версии питона стабильный порядок и поддерживается. В общем случае коллекция "словарь" не подразумевает сохранения порядка элементов, в отличие от списка.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо. Суть понятна!!!. Этот список просто еще используется в разных местах, править его не гуд. Будем обновляться. Решение с нормальными словарями тоже хорошее, спасибо!!!

Comment: eng_rus = {y['name']:y['value'] for x in list_fils for y in x.values()} Это подойдет, еще раз Спасибо!